Getting local coordinate (parented) axis_angle rotation keyframing working in Blender 4.1 Python
As the question says, I'm trying to get local coordinate (parented) axis angle rotation of objects working in keyframing with Blender 4.1 Python.  You may look at the io_scene_x3d import addon for reference, that's where this code mostly came from.  So far, I've only been able to rotate around a moving origin.  I want to animate something similar to bones, but not bones.  I'm not sure if there's another way to do it, but a friend has been encouraging me to do it without bones, so I'm just trying to animate a object and descendants in an object hierarchy with joints as transformed objects and various geometry/shape/mesh.  If there's no way to do this without bones, please tell me.  I am a blender noob, I don't use the GUI except for testing my import code.
 
def translateLocalOrientationInterpolator(node, action, ancestry, to_node):
    key = node.getFieldAsArray('key', 0, ancestry)
    keyValue = node.getFieldAsArray('keyValue', 4, ancestry)

    obj = to_node.blendObject
    obj.rotation_mode = 'AXIS_ANGLE'
    for time, (x, y, z, w) in zip(key, keyValue):
        obj.rotation_axis_angle = (w, x, y, z)
        obj.keyframe_insert(data_path="rotation_axis_angle", frame=time * PREF_TIME_MULT)

Here's another attempt:
def translateLocalOrientationInterpolator(node, action, ancestry, to_node):
    key = node.getFieldAsArray('key', 0, ancestry)
    keyValue = node.getFieldAsArray('keyValue', 4, ancestry)

    obj = to_node.blendObject
    obj.rotation_mode = 'AXIS_ANGLE'
    for time, (x, y, z, w) in zip(key, keyValue):
        obj.rotation_axis_angle = (w, x, y, z)

        parent_matrix = obj.parent.matrix_world
        parent_matrix_inv = parent_matrix.inverted()

        child_matrix = Matrix.Rotation(w, 4, (x, y, z))
        child_matrix = parent_matrix @ child_matrix @ parent_matrix_inv
        obj.matrix_world = child_matrix

        obj.keyframe_insert(data_path="rotation_axis_angle", frame=time * PREF_TIME_MULT)


Note that I've tried to animate this with bones, but I require that several levels of hierarchy be attached below bones (feature points/sites/landmarks/geometry/mesh/shapes).

Is it possible I need to use euler angles or quaternions to get a local rotation?  I think I have plenty of empties.
